# Not giving desired output in access database query

Tags: ms-access

In my Access database, I have three (PERS, QUALIFICATION,WORKED) tables with KNO a common field. 
My code is as under

```
SELECT
    Pers.KNO, Pers.Name, Pers.Company
FROM
    (Pers LEFT JOIN Qualification
    ON Pers.KNO = Qualification.KNO)
    LEFT JOIN Worked
    ON Pers.KNO = Worked.KNO
WHERE
        (((Qualification.Qualification)="CCNA")
    AND ((Qualification.Grade)="A"))
    and ((Pers.Company not like 'IMDT*')
    and ( Pers.Company not like 'MZIN*'))
    and ((Worked.Company not like 'IMDT*')
    and ( Worked.Company not like 'MZIN*'))
GROUP BY Pers.KNO, Pers.Name, Pers.Company;
```

All lines works as desired but this one
`and ((Worked.Company not like 'IMDT*') and ( Worked.Company not like 'MZIN*'))`
is not giving correct output. as per my code people worked in company named  IMDT or MZIN should not be reflected in the output which I get.

But they are included in output. How can I rectify it?

Comment: I am running in access database itself

Comment: Use double quotes for your matching patterns, instead of single ones.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT Pers.kno, Pers.Name, Pers.Company
FROM worked LEFT JOIN (Pers LEFT JOIN qualification ON Pers.kno = qualification.kno) ON worked.kno = Pers.kno
WHERE (((worked.Company) Not Like "IMDT*" And (worked.Company) Not Like "MZIN*"))
GROUP BY Pers.kno, Pers.Name, Pers.Company
HAVING (((Pers.Company) Not Like "MZIN*" And (Pers.Company) Not Like "MZIN*"));

Comment: message comes as u tried to execute the query that does not include the specific expression Worked.Company not like 'IMDT*'as part of aggregate function